# Pointer arithmetic with structs

Tags: c, struct

Couple questions along these lines, but I dont quite understand any of them.

```
struct bundle 
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

void foo(struct bundle *A, int p)
{
    A->x = p;
    A->y = p;
}

main()
{
    struct bundle ptr;
    foo(&ptr, 0);
    //printf("%d",*(ptr + 1)); ISSUE HERE
}
```

My print statement is not working... Any ideas?

I'm using an online C compiler which is giving me this error

```
invalid operands to binary +
```

but I dont think that the compiler has anything to do with it.

I've tried casting it to an `(int *)` but no luck. I am pretty sure I am doing the correct `*(ptr + 1)` and I dont have to do `*(ptr + sizeof(int))` or anything like that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: because `ptr` isn't a pointer

Comment: What did you expect it to print, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ptr` is not a pointer. It's a `struct bundle`. You have to take the address with `&`:

```
printf("%d", *(&ptr + 1));
```

This will of course result in [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), but it's well-formed.

Did you mean `printf("%d", ptr.y);` or `printf("%d", ptr.x + 1);`?